# Excel autofilter - doesn't find trailing 0s

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter, trailing

I have 2 sheets, one the user inputs data used as search criteria and the second sheet is the data being searched. Both my search value cell and column are formatted as a number with 4 decimal places: 0.0000

the user enters value into C6
want to filter search sheet, column 19 or S

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$AX$20000").autofilter Field:=19, criteria1:=Worksheets("Lookup").Range("C6")
```

Example: C6 on lookup sheet = 0.0650 but it sets the autofilter to 0.065 which returns nothing, which for some reason does not = 0.650 which returns appropriate results.

I'm very confused here and not sure how to look this up. Thanks in advance :)

**Edit:** This happens for a data lookup as well (for loop).

```
for i = 1 to LastRow
    If Not IsError(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value) Then
            If strItem = Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                intRow = Trim(fncRemoveAlpha(Replace(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Address, "$", "")))
                
                Me.Cells(12, 6).Value = Worksheets("Data").Cells(intRow, 14)
            end if
   end if
next i
```

I understand it is a text comparison and not a number comparison, but I'm not sure why it isn't a number comparison to begin with. Formatting the cell and/or the data does not seem to resolve this.

Comment: I'll guess that the data on your `Data` sheet is probably using text that looks like numbers instead of being actual numbers.

Comment: You firstly must determine what is the data format of the "Data" sheet, as correctly was suggested in the above comment. If so, you should firstly autofit the column "C:C" and use `.range("C6").Text`.

Comment: If you want to avoid formatting it as the answers illustrate, you can address why the `Data` is not numeric in the first place. Maybe you imported that `Data` using something that did not treat them as numeric values. If you can first change how that data is populated instead, that would probably be a better solution than getting the formatting to match, as that could change.

Comment: The data was imported from an Access DB. Wouldn't that set the data type? I also have the cells formatted as Number with 4 decimals, I tried a custom as well "#0.0000#"

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out [here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/filter-numbers/):

"*When applying a filter for a single number we need to use the number formatting that is applied in the column.*"

So you should amend your code to:

`Criteria1:=Format(Worksheets("Lookup").Range("C6"), "0.0000")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Worksheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$AX$20000").autofilter Field:=19, criteria1:=Worksheets("Lookup").Range("C6").Text
```

The only change is the .Text at the end.

**edit:**
Alright so I devised another solution, one that should work 100% of the time, no matter what formatting you use for either the search value or the data:

```
Dim searchValue As String, searchRange As Range
Set searchRange = Worksheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$AX$20000")
searchValue = Format(Worksheets("Lookup").Range("C6"), searchRange.Cells(2, 1).NumberFormat)
searchRange.AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=searchValue
```

Comment: This can cause problems if the column is not wide enough, as it could return something like `###` instead of the desired value.

Comment: @braX hmm you're right, I just tested this. Well, I'll just leave this here anyway. Maybe Jos Woolley's answer is a better solution but that one would cease to work if OP decides to change the formatting of the data at any point. Although that is probably less of a concern.

Comment: @braX I thought of another solution, can you take a look? This should work right?